# Count unique/distinct item from two tables that have same value

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, *item* and *people*.

```
+--------------+---------------+
| item         | people        |
+--------------+---------------+
| catid        | id            |
| groupid      | parent_id     |
+--------------+---------------+
```

This is content of item table

```
+--------------+---------------+
| catid        | groupid       |
+--------------+---------------+
| 501          | 59            |
| 502          | 59            |
| 503          | 60            |
| 504          | 59            |
+--------------+---------------+
```

This is content of people table

```
+--------------+---------------+
| id           | parent_id     |
+--------------+---------------+
| 501          | 77            |
| 502          | 78            |
| 503          | 77            |
| 504          | 79            |
+--------------+---------------+
```

How can I select all records from *item* table that have groupid = 59, then find record from *people* that have *id* = *catid* from previous result, then count unique value of parent_id from the final result?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desire results.

Comment: select count(distinct p.parent_id) from people p, item i where p.id=i.catid

Comment: @GordonLinoff done. thanks

Comment: @anonyXmous I have edited my question thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using a modification query based on @anonyXmous comment :

```
select count(distinct p.parent_id) from jdl_cck_store_form_warga p, jdl_content i where i.catid='59' and p.id=i.id
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this query to solve the problem:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(people.parent_id)
  FROM people
 WHERE item.groupid = 59 AND item.catid = people.id;
```